# Hash into grouped array

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I'm not very experienced in ruby, so I'm struggling to format a piece of data.

I have this hash, which contains some keys that have the same value, ex:

```
{"key" => "value1", "key2" => "value2", "key3" => "value3", "key4" => "value1", "key5" => "value2" ..}
```

I'm trying to turn this into, an array containing the keys grouped by the values

```
 [["key","key4"],["key2","key5"],["key3"]]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
new_hash = {}
hash.each do |key, value|
  new_hash[value] ||= []
  new_hash[value] << key
end
array = new_hash.values # => [["key", "key4"], ["key2", "key5"], ["key3"]]
```

Comment: Or simply `h.group_by(&:last).map { |_,y| y.map(&:first) }`.

Comment: @NiklasB. Nice. Never really use `group_by` so didn't even think of it.

Comment: @NiklasB. Wait, I just realized you edited that to use `_` and I immediately think of Prolog, but that's just a normal variable in Ruby, correct? (Of course it has special meaning in IRb as well)

Comment: No, it's not a variable. It's more of a placeholder, to say: Ruby, discard that value, I don't need it. That's why `lambda { |x,x| 3 }` fails, while `lambda { |_,_| 3 }` works

Comment: @NiklasB. Although `(1..3).map { |_| _ + 1 }` returns `[2, 3, 4]`, so it must also behave like a variable?

Comment: @NiklasB. Also, curiously, `{ 1 => 4, 2 => 5, 3 => 6 }.map { |_, _| _ }` returns `[4, 5, 6]`.

Comment: Indeed, it does, never tried that. I wouldn't count on this to be universally available though, might well be it's a MRI-specific thing. It's also surprising how something like `[[1,2],[2,3],[3,4]].map { |_,_| _ }` acts. The first value is discarded here, while the second is available as `_` inside the block... I don't see a lot of consistency here. Might be interesting to make a question out of this (how it works, why it's available, if it's specified etc.) :)

Comment: @NiklasB. Agreed, it is odd. I'm digging through the Ruby source now trying to find it. I'm considering making a question, because this is genuinely interesting. `_` for "don't care" is a great feature in Prolog (obviously though lack of unification makes it more useful), nice to have found it exists in Ruby.

Comment: It also exists in Haskell and Python, so it's quite a common idiom.

Comment: @NiklasB. [Question created](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9559561/where-and-how-is-the-underscore-variable-specified-in-ruby), feel free to comment `:)`.

Answer (score 3):

```
hash = {
  "key" => "value1",
  "key2" => "value2",
  "key3" => "value3",
  "key4" => "value1",
  "key5" => "value2"
}

hash.group_by { |key, value| value }.values.map { |pairs| pairs.map &:first }

# => [["key", "key4"], ["key2", "key5"], ["key3"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
hash.group_by{|k,v| v}.map{|k,v| v.reduce([]){|res,n| res << n.first}}
```

Comment: The reduce can be written as a simple `v.map(&:first)`.